# How do you find correlation between two variables in Sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two variables for every user: review_count and fans.

'review_count' gives the number of reviews made by the user and 'fans' gives the number of fans they have.

The data looks like this:

[image]

The data is stored in SQLite. Is there any in built function in SQLite for calculating Correlation between two variables?

Comment: What does "correlation coefficient" mean to you?  You need to calculate the formula, which is possible, but it would help if you provided the formula to be sure the code does what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Is there any inbuilt function/statement in SQL that I could use?

Comment: Warning: not really release worthy yet and only minimally tested (that's my next project): https://github.com/shawnw/useful_sqlite_extensions

Comment: @PrashannaGuru . . . Many databases have built-in functions for the Pearson correlation coefficient.  SQLite is not one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have a built-in square root function.   Nor a built-in power function.  But if you can settle for R^2, then I think the formula is:

```
select (sum( (x - avg_x) * (y - avg_y) ) * sum( (x - avg_x) * (y - avg_y) ) /
       nullif(sum( (x - avg_x) * (x - avg_x) ) * 
              sum( (y - avg_y) * (y - avg_y)), 0
             ) as r_square
from (select t.*, review_cnt as x, fans as y,
             avg(review_cnt) over () as avg_x,
             avg(fans) over () as avg_y
      from t
     ) t;
```

You can check it against the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient).

Comment: What does the R in the above formulae refer to?

Comment: @PrashannaGuru . . . `r` is the common abbreviation for the Pearson correlation coefficient.

Answer (score 8):

I am doing the same Coursera course and this is my solution. Note that in other SQL languages, the covar and cor functions makes it much easier. It wasn't possible to calculate the R-function as there is no SQRT() function in SQLite.

```sql
select avg( (review_count - avg_x) * (fans - avg_y) )*avg( (review_count - avg_x) * (fans - avg_y) )/(var_x*var_y) as R2 
from user, (select 
      avg_x,
      avg_y,
      avg((review_count - avg_x)*(review_count - avg_x)) as var_x, 
      avg((fans - avg_y)*(fans - avg_y)) as var_y 
      from user, (select 
          avg(review_count) as avg_x, 
          avg(fans) as avg_y 
          from user)
  );
```